# regular expression: may or may not contain a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a floating number that might be in the form of 0.1234567 or 1.23e-5 
Here is my python code:

```
import re
def main():
    m2 = re.findall(r'\d{1,4}:[-+]?\d+\.\d+(e-\d+)?', '1:0.00003 3:0.123456 8:-0.12345')
    for svs_elem in m2:
         print svs_elem

main()
```

It prints blank... Based on my test, the problem was in (e-\d+)? part.

Comment: What's the '1:0.00003 3:0.123456 8:-0.12345' ? The string from where you have to extract?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 4):

See emphasis:

```
Help on function findall in module re:
findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
    If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
    list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
    has more than one group.
    Empty matches are included in the result.
```

You have a group, so it’s returned instead of the entire match, but it doesn’t match in any of your cases. Make it non-capturing with `(?:e-\d+)`:

```
m2 = re.findall(r'\d{1,4}:[-+]?\d+\.\d+(?:e-\d+)?', '1:0.00003 3:0.123456 8:-0.12345')
```

Comment: If you want to grab the example I included that shows how the capturing group works, I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-capturing group. The matches are succeeding, but the output is the contents of the optional groups that *don't* actually match.

See the output when your input includes something like `e-6`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d{1,4}:[-+]?\d+\.\d+(e-\d+)?', '1:0.00003 3:0.123456 8:-0.12345e-6')
['', '', 'e-6']
```

With a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d{1,4}:[-+]?\d+\.\d+(?:e-\d+)?', '1:0.00003 3:0.123456 8:-0.12345e-6')
['1:0.00003', '3:0.123456', '8:-0.12345e-6']
```

---

Here's are some simpler examples to demonstrate how capturing groups work and how they influence the output of `findall`. First, no groups:

```
>>> re.findall("a[bc]", "ab")
["ab"]
```

Here, the string "ab" matched the regex, so we print everything the regex matched.

```
>>> re.findall("a([bc])", "ab")
["b"]
```

This time, we put the `[bc]` inside a capturing group, so even though the entire string is still matched by the regex, `findall` only includes the part inside the capturing group in its output.

```
>>> re.findall("a(?:[bc])", "ab")
["ab"]
```

Now, by converting the capturing group to a non-capturing group, `findall` again uses the match of the entire regex in its output.

```
>>> re.findall("a([bc])?", "a")
['']
>>> re.findall("a(?:[bc])?", "a")
['a']
```

In both of these final case, the regular expression as a whole matches, so the return value is a non-empty list. In the first one, the capturing group itself doesn't match any text, though, so the empty string is part of the output. In the second, we don't have a capturing group, so the match of the entire regex is used for the output.

Comment: Thank you! can you explain why the capturing one (the one I wrote) didn't capture the numbers, while using a non-capturing group it captures? I still don't understand how non-capturing works. In (?:...) what does the ? stand for? I just don't understand this although it is intuitive to you

Comment: When your regular expression contains a capturing group `(...)`, the output of the `findall` command contains the contents of the group. In your case, since the capturing group is optional (`(...)?`), the group matches no text, so no text is included in the output. When you make the group a non-capturing group by using `(?:...)` instead of simply `(...)`, `findall` uses the text that matches the entire regex in its output.

Comment: That sounds like for any optional strings (might or might not contained), i should also use non-capturing group to get findall() output something?

Comment: but why re.findall(r'\d{1,4}:[-+]?\d+\.\d+(e-\d+)?', '1:0.00003 3:0.123456 8:-0.12345e-6')   output ['', '', 'e-6'] instead of ['', '', '8:-0.12345e-6'] because the third number is matched completely?

Comment: The third number matches completely, yes, but the output of `findall` *only* includes the part that matches within the capturing group in its output. Generally, you want to use `(?:...)` any time you aren't interested in what the contents matched specifically. It's also more efficient, since the regex engine doesn't need to treat the contents specially.

Comment: Thank you for the examples chepner! They explained capturing and non-capturing groups perfectly. My goal is actually to extract only the floating numbers and get rid of the index(the label before the float number). I am not familiar with group and now a non-capturing group jumps out so I am even more confused. Could you show me how can i extract what i need i this example?

Comment: import re

def main():
    m2 = re.findall(r'\d{1,4}:([-+]?\d+\.\d+(?:e-\d+)?)', '1:0.00003 3:0.123456 8:-0.12345e-5')
    for svs_elem in m2.group(1):
         print svs_elem

main()

Comment: above is what i wrote and python said "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: oh!! I read what you taught me again and I actually don't need to use group because there is only one element in the output of findall() (because it output the capturing group) so I change m2.group(1) to m2 and it works